# jquery unobtrusive validation add validation rules for control in partial loaded multiple times

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a partial that I load on a popup, depending on a value selected from a dropdown list, multiple times. The partial has a textbox that needs to validate. So the problem is that the validation works only on the first partial's text box. About the other one(in this case) it says it is valid. I have created a dummy app to show it here. This is in the partial:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OrderedQuantity, new { name="somename", data_mini = "true", type = "number", @class = "orderedQuantity removeGroupsRequired" })
```

this is on the popup where I load the partial:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("LoadSpecialOffersByOfferGroup", "Orders")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#groupOfferSection').show();
            $.each(data, function (val, partial) {
                $('#specialOrderGroupDetailSection').append(partial);
                var form = $("#mydiv form")
                            .removeData("validator")
                            .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");

                $('#specialOrderGroupDetailSection').trigger('create');
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

            });

            $("#mydiv form .orderedQuantity").each(function() {
                $(this).rules("add", {
                    required: true,
                    messages: {
                        required: "you must provide a quantity!"
                    }
                });
            });


        }
    });
 $('#load').click(function () {
    $("#mydiv form").validate().resetForm();

    $("#mydiv form").data("validator").settings.ignore = ".removeRequired";
    ValidateGroups();

    var form1valid = $("#mydiv form").valid();
    if (form1valid) {

        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        $('#closeOrderItemAddPopup').click();
    }
});
function ValidateGroups() {

    $("#mydiv form").validate();

    if ($("#mydiv form").valid()) {
        alert("valid");
    } else {
        alert("invalid");
    }
}
```

and the controller part for loading the partials:

```
public ActionResult LoadSpecialOffersByOfferGroup()
    {
        List<string> partials = new List<string>();
        IList<SpecialOfferGroupDetailBO> specialOfferGroupDetailBos = new List<SpecialOfferGroupDetailBO>
                                                                          {
                                                                              new SpecialOfferGroupDetailBO
                                                                                  {ItemID = 123}
                                                                          };
        SpecialOfferGroupDetailVM vm = new SpecialOfferGroupDetailVM();
        vm.SpecialOfferGroupID = 1;
        vm.SpecialOfferGroupName = "group 1";
        vm.SpecialOfferGroupDetailBos = specialOfferGroupDetailBos;
        string specialOfferGroupDetailView = RenderRazorViewToString("SpecialOfferGroupDetail", vm);
        partials.Add(specialOfferGroupDetailView);
        IList<SpecialOfferGroupDetailBO> specialOfferGroupDetailBos1 = new List<SpecialOfferGroupDetailBO>
                                                                          {
                                                                              new SpecialOfferGroupDetailBO
                                                                                  {ItemID = 125}
                                                                          };
        SpecialOfferGroupDetailVM vm1 = new SpecialOfferGroupDetailVM();
        vm1.SpecialOfferGroupID = 2;
        vm1.SpecialOfferGroupName = "group 2";
        vm1.SpecialOfferGroupDetailBos = specialOfferGroupDetailBos1;
        string specialOfferGroupDetailView1 = RenderRazorViewToString("SpecialOfferGroupDetail", vm1);
        partials.Add(specialOfferGroupDetailView1);
        JsonResult jsonResult = Json(partials);
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only calls `.validate()` from within your `ValidateGroups` function:

```
function ValidateGroups() {

    $("#mydiv form").validate();

    ....
```

The single most important thing to remember about this plugin is that `.validate()` is not a *testing* method.  It's only the method for *initializing* the plugin on your form.  Most typically, this is done ***once*** on DOM ready or page load.  It's only done once and any subsequent call is ignored.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#mydiv form").validate();  // initialize validation plugin on DOM ready event

    ....
```

Since it seems you're trying to initialize validation on a form that is created dynamically, you would call `.validate()` immediately after your form is created or loaded.

```
$.ajax({
    // create/load your form
    ....
});

$("#mydiv form").validate();  // initialize validation plugin after form is created/loaded

....
```

Comment: nope, doesn't work. I've tried right after the ajax that loads the partials on the popup, and it's not working.

Comment: @bokkie, is unobtrusive validation interfering with it?  Regardless, if you need to call `.validate()` as part of this project, it should get called as I specified.